# Issues with Ubuntu 20.04 and the LG 27UK670 LCD connected via USB-C/TB 4

Tags: 20.04, display, intel-graphics, thinkpad, usb-c

I've been having some issues with various machines of similar specs connected to identical 4k lcd's.

The issues would manifest as the screen blanking out randomly for 1-5s and then reappearing and when doing anything on the screen the blanking would become worse.

The Specs of the machines are as follows:

- Lenovo ThinkPad E14/15 G2
- Intel Core i5 1135G7
- The machines are running Ubuntu 20.04 and Kubuntu.

I've installed all intel-relared stuff including the non-free intel va, mesa and updating to the latest mainline kernel, creating and changing the Xorg config etc..

monitoring kern.log didn't show anything out of the ordinary and the display was detected fine. At this point I don't even know what logs to attach.

I've had to resort to disabling Displayport 1.2 in the OSD on the monitor to get any usable output but it's now only able to run at the cinematic 30Hz.

Please help.